# Retrieving data from classes that use TPH in entityframework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles, tph

So I started my project using the identity scaffolding and created an application user class that inherits from identity user

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace test6.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

       
    }
}
```

and some classes that inherit from this class

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace test6.Models
{
    public class Teacher : ApplicationUser
    {
        
        
        public string Course { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

I have set up my roles and they seem to be working fine, however my problem is that I am trying to retrieve data from users and when retrieving data that is specific to a class that has inherited from applicationuser like Course from Teacher I get an error which is because my usermanager is initialised with ApplicationUser

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
```

The method I'm using to retrieve users is this

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ListTeacher()
        {
            var users = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Teacher");

            return View(users);
        }
```

So I have tried to initialise usermanager with Teacher to test but I get an error I think it's because in the dependancy I used ApplicationUser and I don't think you can use more than one. So my question is what possible solutions are there for this.(Sorry if my question isn't great or my explanation is poor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I've found a solution, turns out you can add another dependancy.

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<Teacher>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<Teacher, IdentityRole>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddDefaultUI();
```

With this I can initialise usermanager with Teacher and so far it has worked.